# How to fix container compressing in the browser(not taking up available space)

Tags: css, typescript, flexbox, react-redux

I am trying to display a web page inside my home page. The navigation link provided is working fine but the page is not taking up available space. It is compressed to certain height and is in a scrollable view inside that height.

I added height: -webkit-fill-available; and it worked, and similarly added -moz for mozilla but doesnt seem like a genuine fix. Is there any thing that i can fix this by changing flex conditions?

I am using the following style

```
style={{ 
display: "flex", 
height:"100%", 
flexDirection: "column",
flex: "auto" 
}}
```

Expected: 
Web page must be displayed completed instead of inside a container with compressed height

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem but it seems that you are using flexbox and in this case, you can use `align-items: stretch` to stretch flex items.